# Python: How to Iterate over selenium webelement list and get index?

Tags: python, selenium

i have a selenium webelement list that contains three webelement object .i want to get index of each element using for loop. How can i do it in python?

currently am doing like this:

```
countries=Select(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="id_country"]')).options
for index, value in countries:
   print index
```

but it give me error

```
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable
```

Comment: could you share what you have tried actually ?

Comment: i have added more explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try the following example

```
select_box = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="id_country"]')
options = [x for x in select_box.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")] #this part is cool, because it searches the elements contained inside of select_box and then adds them to the list options if they have the tag name "options"
for element in options:
    print element.get_attribute("value") # or append to list or whatever you want here
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate` with the `for` loop:

```
countries=Select(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="id_country"]')).options
for index, value in enumerate(countries):
   print index
```

That would print

```
0
1
2
```

You can specify the starting index too if you don't want it to be zero indexed:

```
countries=Select(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="id_country"]')).options
for index, value in enumerate(countries, 10):
   print index


10
11
12
```